# Creating 30 arc-second polygon grid on Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector-grid

In ArcGIS you can do this with Data Reviewer > Create Polygon Grid Wizard. Is there an equivalent tool on Earth Engine?

I'm hoping to repeat a function over each square kilometer to create a density map, and need a polygon grid to do so.

Answer (score 1):

See this article: https://medium.com/google-earth/random-samples-with-buffering-6c8737384f8c

```
var proj = ee.Projection("EPSG:4326").scale(1/120, 1/120)
var cells = ee.Image.random().multiply(1000000).int().reproject(proj)
Map.addLayer(cells.randomVisualizer())
```

Then you can use that layer as a label band in `reduceConnectedComponents` to do whatever per-cell computation you need to do.  If you absolutely must have polygons, you could call `reduceToVectors` on that (but you should try hard to avoid that, performance is vastly better if you stay in image space).